# How to create certificate with access to private key

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, certificate-authority, google-cloud-certificate-authority

Using the Cloud console, one can create Certificates in *Certificate Authority* and gets to download the Private Key after creation.

Now I want to do the same - but from Golang.
From the API it is not really obvious to me how to access the private key of the generated certificate, though.